# How to format the output of the html5 datepicker when type="week"?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-datepicker

I'm trying to format the output of the datepicker, when the type selected is week.

The format I'm going for is YYWW.

I find plenty on formatting the output of a regular type="date" datepicker, but not the week datepicker.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<div class="container p-5">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 offset-sm-3 mx-auto">
    <!-- HTML here -->
    <input type="week" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i didn't get why you need to change it's format to yyww, let's your example: you want output 1835, now how can you identify that it' 2018 or 1918 or 1818 or 2118? and for that you dont want to give user to select such like week _ _ , _ _ _ _.

Comment: The idea is to select the current date from a datepicker. But the output would not display MM-DD-YYYY. I want it to display YYWW.

Comment: you mean to say output means value that generated internally by weekpicker correct?

Comment: For example, I want to select today's date from the datepicker. But, I want the output to display the YYWW (1837).

Answer (score -1):

HTML

```
<input type="week" required="required">
```

CSS

```
input[type="week"] {
appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;
color: #95a5a6;
font-family: "Helvetica", arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 18px;
border:1px solid #ecf0f1;
background:#ecf0f1;
padding:5px;
display: inline-block !important;
visibility: visible !important;
}
```

I edit my previous answer. Maybe this can help to format output for type="week". Check http://jsfiddle.net/V2Q58/1590/. Change type from date to week.

#### DISCLAIMER: Output made by Adriano Monecchi

Comment: Did you read the question? I'm trying to format the output of the datepicker when the type is week.

Comment: My question says the output I'm trying to achieve is "YYWW"... Please try your fiddle. It doesn't do that, no matter the input type.

Comment: I used a datepicker class. and input yyyy-mm.. Click here [http://jsfiddle.net/d8gnt9bw/](http://jsfiddle.net/d8gnt9bw/)

Comment: It doesn't work. It outputs the yyyy mm, which isn't what I'm looking for. As I stated in the original question... I'm looking for YYWW (for example **1835**, which is the year 2018, and the 35th week). Does that make sense?

Answer (score -1):

What exactly do you need to format? 
You can control min and max as below

```
<input type="week"  max="2017-W52" min="2017-W01" class="form-control">
```

Comment: When I click on any date in the datepicker, I want the output to display as yyww (year year week week). If I select today's date, the output should read 1835, because it is 2018, and we are in the 35th week.